# How to train model with large of categorical features :: RStudio Crashes

Tags: r, amazon-ec2, memory-management, xgboost

I have a dataset with over `800K` rows and `66` columns/features. I am training `xgboost` model with `carte` with `5k-Fold Cross-Validation`. However, due to the following two columns my R session always crashes; even though I used amazon instance with following specs. I am using

Amazon EC2 Instance Types

`m5.4xlarge    16  64  EBS-Only    Up to 10    3,500`

```
# A tibble: 815,885 x 66
   first_tile             last_tile                  
   <fct>                  <fct>                      
 1 Filly Brown            Body of Evidence           
 2 The Dish               The Hunger Games           
 3 Waiting for Guffman    Hell's Kitchen N.Y.C.      
 4 The Age of Innocence   The Lake House             
 5 Malevolence            In the Name of the Father  
 6 Old Partner            Desperate Measures         
 7 Lady Jane              The Invasion               
 8 Mad Dog Time           Eye of the Needle          
 9 Beauty Is Embarrassing Funny Lady                 
10 The Snowtown Murders   Alvin and the Chipmunks    
11 Superman II            Pina                       
12 Leap of Faith          Capote                     
13 The Royal Tenenbaums   Dead Men Don't Wear Plaid  
14 School for Scoundrels  Tarzan                     
15 Rhinestone             Cocoon: The Return         
16 Burn After Reading     Death Defying Acts         
17 The Doors              Half Baked                 
18 The Wood               Dance of the Dead          
19 Jason X                Around the World in 80 Days
20 Dragon Wars            LOL   


 ## Model Training
        libray(caret)
        set.seed(42)
        split <- 0.8
        train_index <- createDataPartition(data_tbl$paid, p = split, list = FALSE)
        data_train  <- data_tbl[train_index, ]
        data_test <-   data_tbl[-train_index, ]


    ## Summarise The Target Variable
    table(dat_train$paid) / nrow(data_train)


    ## Create Train/Test Indexes
    ## Create train/test indexes
    ## preserve class indices
    set.seed(42)
    my_folds <- createFolds(data_train$paid, k = 5)

    # Compare class distribution
    i <- my_folds$Fold1
    table(data_train$paid[i]) / length(i)

    ## Reusing trainControl
    my_control <- trainControl(
      summaryFunction = twoClassSummary,
      classProbs = TRUE,
      verboseIter = TRUE,
      savePredictions = TRUE,
      index = my_folds
      )

    model_xgb <- train(
        paid ~. ,
        data = data_train,
        metric = "ROC",
       method = "xgbTree",
       trControl = myControl)
```

- Can you suggest me someway I can get around with this memory problem every time?
- Is there a way I can do some sort of one hot coding for these features?
- I would appreciate any suggestion or help?
- Is there a way I should know how big machine I need?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to tackle such issues in the world of ML.

- Do you really need all the 66 features? Have you performed feature selection techniques? Have you tried getting rid of features which do not contribute to your prediction in any way? Check out some feature selection mechanisms for R here:
  https://dataaspirant.com/2018/01/15/feature-selection-techniques-r/
- Assuming you need most or all of your features, and now you want to encode these categorical variables, one hot seems a popular choice but there are other encoding techniques out there too. One of my choices would be binary encoding. However, there are other encoding techniques you can explore too: https://towardsdatascience.com/smarter-ways-to-encode-categorical-data-for-machine-learning-part-1-of-3-6dca2f71b159
- xgboost also has subsampling mechanism. Did you try training with a sample of your data? Check out the subsampling feature of xgboost here: https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/parameter.html